# onAuthenticationSuccess of my Custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler is not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a problem with configuring two Spring Security adapters. One will be using form login, and the other will be basic authentication. The problem is that I could not invoke the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method in my `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` after successfully authenticated through the basic authentication.

The following is my Java config. Thank you for your input.

```
@EnableWebSecurity

public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    ...

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/auth/login")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin**")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/**")
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .formLogin()
                            .successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .permitAll()
                            .failureUrl("/login?error")
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login_check")
                            .usernameParameter("username")
                            .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and()
                        .logout()
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .and()
                        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
                    .and()
                        .csrf()
                    .and()
                        .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(internalSecretKey, userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository))
                        .key(internalSecretKey)
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);
        }
    }

    private AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(){

        AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter filter = new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the custom filter.

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Checking headers and parameters for authentication token...");

        String token = null;

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (httpServletRequest.getParameter("token") != null) {
            token = httpServletRequest.getParameter("token");
            System.out.println("Found token '" + token + "' in request parameters");
        } else if (httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authentication-token") != null) {
            token = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authentication-token");
            System.out.println("Found token '" + token + "' in request headers");
        }

        if (token != null) {
            authenticateUser(httpServletRequest, user);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void authenticateUser(HttpServletRequest request, UserDetails user) {
        ...

        SecurityContext sc = securityContextProvider.getSecurityContext();
        sc.setAuthentication(auth.authenticate(authentication));
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call your `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. If you override `doFilter`you have to call the handlers manually.

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ([spring AuthenticationSuccessHandler not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603497/spring-authenticationsuccesshandler-not-called)) , I'll complete with the solution code :

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
//CODE
            
  customAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(
  httpServletRequest, 
  (HttpServletResponse)response,
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
                
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```