# spring AuthenticationSuccessHandler not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot security and trying to implement an AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
but it's ignored when I authenticate. Currently I've not implemented any Roles.

I have an AbstractController containing an /authenticate endpoint and
a CustomerController which extends it, this is why I have :

```
            .loginProcessingUrl("customer/authenticate").permitAll()
```

I have

> @Component public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter

And added as a filterBefore in my WebSecurity like so :

> .addFilterBefore(jwtFitler,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.clas)

**What I've tried :**

1. Removing "customer" prefix in loginProcessingUrl

> ```
>           .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").permitAll()
> ```

2. Removing

> ```
>           .addFilterBefore(jwtFitler, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
> ```

3. Using SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler instead of AuthenticationProvider

**CODE :**

WebSecurity configuration :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REGISTER_USERS_URL, LOG_IN_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", HOME, GET_ACCOUNTS_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**.css").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("customer/authenticate").permitAll()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFitler, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

----------------------- **EDIT WITH SOLUTION** ----------------------

**Solution :**

Call the authentication success handler before doFilter ;

```
    authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(
       httpServletRequest, 
       httpServletResponse,                      
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());


filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
```

**Complete code :**

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
                                
    @Autowired
      private AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl 
       authenticationSuccessHandler;
                
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, 
      @NotNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
      @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, 
   IOException {
                                    
    //SOLUTION        
          authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(httpServletRequest, 
    httpServletResponse,                                        
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Your custom filter probably doesn't call the authentication success handler. See the comments on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774023/onauthenticationsuccess-of-my-custom-authenticationsuccesshandler-is-not-called

Comment: Thanks that works Ive updated the question with the solution.